# How to remove /posts/ from URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, routes

How can I also show a blog post without `/posts/` in the URL?

```
http://www.anthonygalli.com/posts/i-walk-the-line
http://www.anthonygalli.com/posts/50-shades-of-galli
http://www.anthonygalli.com/posts/tips-for-regaining-momentum
```

Shortened Version (Goal of Question):

```
http://www.anthonygalli.com/i-walk-the-line
http://www.anthonygalli.com/50-shades-of-galli
http://www.anthonygalli.com/tips-for-regaining-momentum
```

I have `post` as a MVC.

**routes.rb**

```
resources :posts
get    'about'   => 'posts#about'
get    'feed'    => 'posts#feed'
get    'subscribe' => 'posts#subscribe'
```

Comment: you can use `'/:title' => 'posts#show'` and `resources :posts ,:except => :show`

Comment: The latter line creates this error: `undefined local variable or method 'except' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007ff02d549fc8>` I would like for both versions of the link to work, i.e. shortened version & current version @uzaif

Comment: `get :title => 'posts#show'` try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes should be updated to look something like this:

```
resources :posts
get    'about'   => 'posts#about'
get    'feed'    => 'posts#feed'
get    'subscribe' => 'posts#subscribe'
get    ':id'     => 'posts#show', :as => :post_by_slug
```

That `as` option will be important for linking to your new route if you want to link to the `/post/`-less paths:

```
<%= link_to post.title, post_by_slug_path(post) %>
```

P. S. I believe that the new route will need to be listed last in your routes so that the routes before it can have precedence. (Otherwise, trying to visit `/about` would try to load a post with a slug named `about` instead of the `posts#about` action. You should try this and see if that's true.)

Answer (score 2):

Change your `routes.rb` to:

```
resources :posts, path: '/' do
  collection do
    get 'about'
    get 'feed'
    get 'subscribe'
  end
end
```

For documentation on Rails routing check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Hey sir. I ran into a problem. I updated `routes.rb` in question. For example if a person goes to `about`, `feed`, or `subscribe`  they will get error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Post):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:61:in 'find_post'` if I add to `routes.rb`: `resources :posts, path: '/'` Otherwise it works great :)

Comment: hello! did it work with the latest change to routes?

Comment: Your answer works with the collection, but Chris's answer works better because of the `slug_path` capabilities. Thanks for your help! I gave you props elsewhere to make up for it :)

Answer (score 0):

Resource generates the standard CRUD urls, so you have to specify the posts route specifically. Something like this

```
get '/desired-url' => 'posts#index'
```

Comment: Each new post I create will create a new `desired post` so that won't work. It's also about the show page not the index page. Thanks for trying though good sir!